Congruence obstructions for three consecutive powerful numbers
A powerful number is an integer $m$ such that if $p$ is prime and $p \mid m$ then $p^2 \mid m$.
Powerful numbers can be represented in the form $m=u^2 v^3$.
Erdos conjectured that three consecutive powerful numbers don't
exist.
Assume $(a-1,a,a+1)$ is a triple of consecutive powerful numbers.
Choose integers $n,A$ and set $a=A$ and assume the system
$$x_1^2 x_2^3=A-1, y_1^2 y_2^3=A+1$$ doesn't have solution modulo $n$.
Then over the integers powerful triple with $a \equiv A \pmod{n}$ doesn't
exist.
Some examples with $n$ square:
n | A congruence obstruction
4 [1, 3]
9 [2, 4, 5, 7]
16 [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15]
25 [4, 6, 9, 11, 14, 16, 19, 21]
36 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]
49 [6, 8, 13, 15, 20, 22, 27, 29, 34, 36, 41, 43]


Q1 Can we find $n$ and congruence obstructions to show non-existence
of more naturally defined powerful triples?


Q2 Can we show that for some even $B$ the triple with $a=B^k$ doesn't
exist for all $k$? (For odd $B$ this is visible with naked eye)


What are "more naturally defined powerful triples"?

There are many powerful numbers with distance 2 - see https://oeis.org/A076445 So you cannot prove much about non-existence of powerful pairs $(A-1,A+1)$ without using powerfulness of $A$ itself.

@MaxAlekseyev I mean results of the form $A$ can't be a power of $6$ or $A$ can't be 30-th power.

EDIT: corrected my response to Q2.
Q1: if I understood the question correctly then the answer is negative. Indeed we may assume $(2B,n)=1$ and taking $k=\varphi(n^2)$ we have $n^2|B^k-1,\,n\nmid B^k+1$, so there is no obstruction stemming from $n$.
Q2: I will show that $2^k-1$ can never be powerful, under the assumption that there are no order-3 Wieferich primes, i.e. $2^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p^3}$ (I realize that this is one hell of an assumption, but perhaps the arguments below can be modified into something more useful).
Assume the contrary and let $k$ be the minimal counterexample. If $k$ is even then since $2^{k/2}-1,\,2^{k/2}+1$ are coprime they are both powerful, so $k/2$ is a smaller counterexample - a contradiction.
We now treat the case when $k>2$ is prime. Assume by way of contradiction that $2^k-1$ is powerful. Since $2^k-1$ is not a square, we have $p^3|2^k-1$ for some prime $p>2$. Then $\mathrm{ord}(2\bmod p^3)|k$ is not divisible by $p$ and so must divide $p-1$ and $p$ is an order-3 Wieferich prime, contrary to our assumption.
Hence assume $k$ is odd and composite and let $p>2$ be the smallest prime factor of $k$. Write $k=pm$. We have $2^k-1=ab,\,a=2^m-1,\,b=1+2^m+2^{2m}+\ldots+2^{(p-1)m}$.
First I claim that $p\nmid a$. Indeed if $p|a$ then $2^m\equiv 1\pmod p$ and $(m,p-1)>1$, so $m$ and hence $k$ has a prime factor smaller than $p$ - a contradiction.
Next I claim that $(a,b)=1$. Indeed $b\equiv p\pmod a$ and $(a,p)=1$ so $(a,b)=1$.
Since $ab$ is powerful so is $a=2^m-1$, contradicting the minimality of $k$.

Interesting, thanks. I think if your proof that $2^k-1$ is never powerful is correct, then this will imply infinitely many non-Wieferich primes, which is open problem. I would recommend asking new question about this. Check the reference at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/394507/must-mersenne-numbers-be-divisible-by-arbitrary-large-primes-with-exponent-one

Does Q2 work for $k=p$?

@joro You are right, my argument runs into the Wieferich prime issue. I updated my answer.

@joro In fact it looks like it's enough to exclude order-3 Wieferich primes. While this is still likely beyond reach, at least we know that these numbers should not exist.

Consider asking question if this order 3 result is new. As far as I can tell it is new (if correct).

Doesn't your result imply that if there are no order-3 Wieferich primes then there will be infinitely many non-Wieferich primes? The linked reference asks when 2^k-1 is powerful.

It appears that it does.

In fact it appears (from a passage in Ribenboim's 13 Lectures on Fermat's Last Theorem) that Puccioni proved something more general in 1968, but I am unable to find the paper online.

Interesting discussion. The upshot is that if $2^n-1$ is powerful, then the minimal $k\mid n$ such that $2^k-1$ is powerful is a prime number, and every prime $p$ satisfying $p^3\mid 2^k-1$ is an order-3 Wieferich prime (since $k\mid p-1$ implies $p^3\mid 2^{p-1}-1$ as well). In particular, $2^n-1$ is divisible by the cube of an order-3 Wieferich prime. Now if there are only finitely many non-Wieferich primes, say $p_1,\dotsc,p_k$, then $n:=\prod_j p_j(p_j-1)$ is admissible above, hence an order-3 Wieferich prime exists. This last step is due to Kalmynin, see https://mathoverflow.net/q/394507

Do you have opinion about the question The smallest solution to 2^(2k)−1=powerful https://mathoverflow.net/questions/395153/the-smallest-solution-to-22k-1-textpowerful

Looks like Puccioni's proof is on p.3 of https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81946884.pdf

Thanks for looking this up.
